# Django log not work in models

Tags: python, django, logging

This days I am using log for django, I config the LOGGING in settings.py; but it's only work in views, and not work in models or other files, I use nginx+uwsgi+supervisord to deploy,the following is my LOGGING value, does any config is wrong?

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': True,
'formatters': {
    'standard': {
        'format': "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
        'datefmt': "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'null': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
    },
    'logfile': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
        'filename': BASE_DIR + "/log/django.log",
        'maxBytes': 10 * 1024 * 1024,
        'backupCount': 2,
        'formatter': 'standard',
    },
    'console': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'standard'
    },
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
},

'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'logfile'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True
    },
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'logfile'],
        'propagate': True,
        'level': 'WARN',
    },
    'django.db.backends': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': False,
    },
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': True,
    },

}
```

}

Comment: Show us please the example of log call in your models. How do you instantiate the logger instance?